# While loop did not ask for input

Tags: c++

Hi I just got into coding while on my sem break and now practicing by written a simple odd or even bet so I made a small UI as bellow

```
int Option()
{
    int UI;
    bool Conformation = 0;
    while (Conformation == 0)
    {
    cout << "For odd enter 1 , for even enter 2\n Insert : ";
    cin >> UI;
    Conformation = 0;
        switch (UI)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "You have selected odd \n are you sure?\n 1.Yes 2.NO \n Insert :";
            cin >> Conformation;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "You have selected even \n are you sure? 1.Yes 2.NO \n Insert :";
            cin >> Conformation;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid entery please enter another value\n";
            Conformation = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return UI;
}
```

I expected it to loop through line 8 "cin >> UI;" when Conformation = 0 , but it just skip any form of "cin"

thank in advance.

Comment: Does it print out the prompts without waiting for any inputs?

Comment: Yes it just go through other thing but not the cin. so it become a infinite loop. :(

Comment: That means you have corrupted `cin` somewhere.  Use `if(!cin) { std::cout << "cin in error state\n"; }` and place that after each `cin` before this function is called to find out where it `cin` fails.

Comment: @nathanOliver I don't know about this but does a bool take an int from a std::cin also by assigning it within the code?

Comment: My god why did I even used bool , and use 1 and 2 as input value , thank you :D . Much appreciated.

Comment: @FirstStep Oops.  I didn't see it was a `bool`.  I thought it was an `int` from the `cout`s.  Good spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
cout << "You have selected odd \n are you sure?\n 1.Yes 2.NO \n Insert :";
cin >> Conformation;
```

Use of `1` or `2` for `Confirmation` is most likely tripping you up since `Confirmation` is of type `bool`.

I suggest changing the type of `Confirmation` to `int`.

Comment: @HimariNoihara, glad I was able to help.